# How to add `uib-tabset` in `infowindowTemplate` of Google Map

Tags: html, google-maps, infowindow

How i can add `uib-tabset` in `infowindowTemplate` of Google Map. I have try the following code but does not work.

```
var infowindowTemplate = [
                `<uib-tabset active="active">`,
                `<uib-tab index=\'0\' heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>`,
                `<uib-tab index=\'1\' heading="Static title2">testing</uib-tab>`,
                `</uib-tabset>`,
               //Other code
            ].join("\n");
```

**Note:** I have also searched but unfortunately does not find any solution.
[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/hT8Kw/

Comment: @Zubairsadiq thanks for your response but i wants `uib-tabset` as given above in my code